# Should set contain only distinct elements in Zermelo-Fraenkel Set Theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am studying set theory and can not understand very basic concept about elements of any specific set. Should they all be distinct?

> In mathematics, a set is a collection of distinct elements.
> [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics))

But in [Zermelo-Fraenkel Set Theory](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Zermelo-Fraenkel_Set_Theory) I can not find Axiom about: all elements of the set are distinct.

Is it legal to have a set: `{1,1,1}` or `{a,a,a}`?

Comment: Yes; due to [Extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality), set $\{ a \}$ is equal to set $\{ a,a \}$

Comment: See [Multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) for a different concept of set that allows for multiple instances for each of its elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase " a collection of distinct elements" is an informal way to say that in a set, repetition is not taken into account, or, more accurately, that there is no repetition ( nor any order) in a set as such.

Note : there is no explicit definition of a set in axiomatic set theory.

The extensionality principle says that , as soon as set A and set B have exactly the same elements, they are equal ( meaning : identical) , and reciprocally, that as soon as they are identical, they are co-extensional.

In virtue of this axiom $A=\{a,a,a\}$ and $B=\{a\}$ are identical . ( Can you point out any object that belongs to A but not to B  , or, inversely, to B but not to A? )

Note : since $A= B$ and $B$ has only one element, $A$ has only one element, namely, the object $a$. In counting the elements of a set, the occurrences of the same object should all be counted as only one object.

Note : what I said does not apply to n-tuples; the ordered pair $<a,a>$ has 2 elements, not only one.

Comment: It is clear that A=B. Is it legal to write A={1,1,1}?

Comment: Oleg Dats: I think most people would consider it legal to write $\{1,1,1\} = \{1\},$ but occasionally you'll find a "know-it-all" (who isn't) who says that the notion $\{1,1,1\}$ is incorrect. Note that the issue with $\{1,1,1\}$ only involves **notations** for sets, not with the actual abstract concept of a set.

Comment: It definitely should be legal. When you write $\{x_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ you don't want to always assume that the sequence has no repetition.